# How to handle (partially) dependant aggregate roots?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have domain concept of `Product`.

`Product` have some `GeneralDetails`, lets say: `sku, name, description`.
At the same time, `Product` have some `ProductCalculations` part where accountants can put different values like `purchasePrice, stockLevelExpenses, wholeSalesPrice, retailPrice`.

So, so far, `Product` would look something like:

```
class Product{
   GeneralDetails Details;
   ProductCalculations Calculations;

   ChangeDetails(GeneralDetails details){}
   Recalculate(ProductCalculations calculations{}

}
```

This setup would make `Product` an aggregate root. But now, i want to split it in a way that Product manager can input/update product details but then that accountant can step in and intependently change calculations for given product without concurrency issues.
That would suggest splitting it into 2 separate aggregate roots.

But then, deleting `ProductDetails` aggregate must mean deleting `ProductCalculations` too and it should happen in transactional way.

Assuming they are 2 aggregate roots, meaning they have 2 separate repositories with corresponding `Delete` methods, how to implement this as an atomic transaction?

The only thing i can think about is to raise event when `ProductDetails` gets deleted, have a handler (`DomainService`) that uses some special repository that handles transactions over multiple aggregate roots.

Is there some problem with that approach and/or is there some better way to handle it?

PS.
I cannot allow eventual consistency when `ProductDetails` is deleted.

PS2.
Based on comments from @Jon, `Details` and `Calculations` create&delete should be synced in a way that when `Details` are created/deleted, `Calculations` should also be created/deleted.
On the other hand, their updates should be completely independent.

Comment: You seem to have weighed the pros and cons of deleting the 2 aggregates in an atomic way. If you're going to do it, why not just start the transaction at the beginning of your Application Service method, call the two `repository.Delete()`s and conclude the transaction?

Comment: Also: http://udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/

Comment: @guillaume31 yes yes, i have read that post. i have never actually deleted an entity in my life in db:). its always a flag. but for simplicity i speak in crud terms. good call, anyways! thanks for that!

Comment: @guillaume31 yes, if transactions are the only way to do it then starting a transaction at the begining of app service is definitely one option. although, personally, i would prefer in that case transaction closer to db regardless of it not being purest solution because that way app domain lost part of control; a bit of business rules leaked out. but i would be willing to pay that price. /i just wanted to check if there is some other pattern to handle/model it differently.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to your question depends somewhat on what data storage technology you're using and your data storage model, because if you can push operation transactionality to the data layer, things get much easier.

If you're using a document-oriented database (Cosmos DB, MongoDB, etc...), I would model and store your `Product` aggregate (including `Details` and `Calculations`) as a single document and you get the atomic transaction and concurrency checking for free from the database.

If you must store these as separate documents/records in your data store, then providing atomic transactions and concurrency checking becomes your concern.  For years folks (especially those using Entity Framework) have been using the [Unit of Work pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) to batch up multiple repository operations and submit them to the database as a single operation ([EF-specific UoW implementation](https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/repository-and-unit-of-work-pattern/)).  Rob Conery suggests [here](https://rob.conery.io/2014/03/03/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/) that a better option is to use Command objects to encapsulate a multi-part operation that needs to be executed as a single transaction.

In any event, I would encourage you to keep the management of this operation within `Product`, so that consumers of `Product` are unaware of what's going on during the save - they just blissfully call `product.SaveAsync()` and they don't need to know whether that's causing one record update or ten.  As long as `Product` is injected with the repositories it needs to get the job done, there's no need to have a separate domain service to coordinate this operation.  There's nothing wrong with `Product` listening for events that its children raise and responding appropriately.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for your answer! could you please just clarify if i understand correctly - in that case 2 users editing different parts of a `Product` would still not be able to work simultaneously, correct? (PS. i am working with document-oriented db)

Comment: You're welcome! Right, in either case (whether the entire aggregate is stored as a single doc or you're using a unit of work or command to batch the multiple operations into a single submit), the database is capable of checking for concurrency violations on submit as long as you have told it to do so. (In Cosmos this means you are using an AccessCondition and passing the ETag from your retrieve when replacing your document.)

Since you're using a document-oriented db and your child objects in your model are not unbounded collections, I would just store the aggregate as a single document.

Comment: yes, then i understand. that's exactly what my first model version looked like but again, i want to have completely concurrency conflict-free solution. Because, if you think about it, person entering in a product or changing its name will never see a calculations screen and he should never get error ("there is new version - reload your document") caused by the data he never sees nor is interested in. (btw, yes, its cosmos-db and i don't use any ORM) so, everyhing points to 2 aggregate roots option except for their lifetime (create/delete) which should be synced.

Comment: Ah, I think I see.  Sorry for my misunderstanding.  So you only need a transaction to span `Details` and `Calculations` on a *delete*; for an *update*, these two entities will be updated independently and don't need to be wrapped in a transaction.  Right?

Comment: yes, exactly. sorry if i wasn't clear enough explaining it. / I've added clarification at the end of my question.

Comment: No problem - we're good now. Then yeah, I think I would store them as two separate documents then and treat DELETE as a special case.  Cosmos DB guarantees atomicity for operations performed within a stored procedure.  Assuming your `GeneralDetails` and `ProductCalculations` documents for a given `Product` are in the same collection and partition (stored procs can't span partitions), then you could just have a stored procedure to handle the delete.

Comment: great we're on the same line now!;) i'm not worried about cosmos-db side, that one i know well. my dilemmas are around app side and how to do it 'in ddd manner'. so, is having a domain service that creates/delets both models and have dedicated repository for that service (that runs stored procedure / transaction on db side) a proper ddd solution?

Comment: I think it depends on how you will be using `GeneralDetails` and `ProductCalculations`. Will it ever make sense to access and work with them in isolation (apart from `Product`)? If not, I think it's correct to think about `Product` as a single aggregate in your domain (even if its children are stored separately in the db) and your `Product` object can have awareness about what's been modified in its children, especially if you're accessing the children through via the parent `Product`...

Comment: ... or, if product managers and accountants are working in separate bounded contexts, it may make sense to have a separate `Product` aggregate tailored to each bounded context.  (It seems I may be raising more questions than I'm helping answer at this point - my apologies!)

Comment: (You may notice that I keep avoiding talking about a separate domain service.  While domain services certainly have their place, to the extent that logic can be encapsulated within an aggregate, especially when it's not crossing aggregate boundaries, the cleaner and more intuitive the domain model's API will be in my opinion.  I tend to reserve my use of domain services for situations where I'm crossing aggregate boundaries.)

Comment: at this point of time you definitely are raising more questions than offering answers but thats nothing to apologize for - i am truly thankful for that! / a separate bounded context is one way i thougt about but essentially it still doesnt solve concurrency conflicts, does it? they could still occur. also, having topmost `Product` aware of changes of its children - doesnt that violate the rule that aggregates should be changed/saved as a whole?

Comment: or are you talking about case where `Product` is an aggregate root whose repository would have `SaveDetails` and `SaveCalculations` methods?

Comment: Possibly, yes.  Or maybe you have a separate repository for `Details` and for `Calculations`; `Product` has a reference to both.  You control access to `Details` and `Calculations` through `Product`, perhaps via `Product.SetDetails` and `Product.SetCalculations` (or maybe if you have a `Product` tailored to Accounting you surface the child properties that Accounting uses as top-level props on their version of `Product`).  Then `Product.SaveAsync()` knows what has changed and how it needs to save itself by invoking the appropriate repository.

Comment: I'm just thinking out loud and offering possibilities as food for thought.  Often when faced with design decisions like this I have to pick the way that seems most right to me and implement it to see how it looks/feels, how is it for consumers to interact with my domain model, what kind of issues do I run into, etc...

Comment: yes, i know what you mean. from all i thought about it so far an option of leaving it to db side with a trigger to create/delete `Calculations` when `Details` are created/deleted is best option for me but i am not sure if it violates something from ddd perspective.

Answer (score 2):

> " I cannot allow eventual consistency when ProductDetails is deleted"

Why not? What would be the business cost of having `Inventory.Product` exist while `Finance.Product` doesn't or vice-versa?

> "but then that accountant can step in and intependently change calculations for given product"

That's pretty much what eventual consistency is, no?

If you really can't have eventual consistency then use a domain service to create/delete two distinct aggregate roots in a single transaction, but ask yourself how you are going to do that if the information is not entirely provided by the same end user?

Comment: well, business cost would be accountants work time spent for nothing, confusion, syncing over phone, inventory not accurate...many things. / it doesnt need to be all info provided from the t=0 (and will not be). its just important that their creation/deletion happen at exactly same time.

Comment: about the option with service and transaction: is it bad to have dedicated repository for creation of those 2 simoultaniously? asking because then i could move transaction to db actually, which i would prefer. or is it a must to have transaction on app side? (from ddd perspective)

Comment: btw, separate work on updates is not eventual consistentcy since those are 2 aggregates. when i talked about eventual consistency i meant strictly create/delete.

Comment: I'd prefer this to be handled in a domain service using 2 distinct repositories while having the transaction handled in the application layer. This way it's clear that the business process requires both ARs to get created/deleted simultaneously. Coming back to eventual consistency, "it doesnt need to be all info provided from the t=0 (and will not be). its just important that their creation/deletion happen at exactly same time". Honestly I don't understand how the creation could happen at the same time while the information may not be provided at the same time.

Comment: In which state would you initialize `ProductCalculations` if such data is not yet known by the inventory manager entering the `ProductGeneralDetails` for a new product? If you only want to create a placeholder `ProductCalculations` then I see little difference between this and not creating one at all or not immediately. " business cost would be accountants work time spent for nothing"... could you expand on this? What scenario do you fear?

Comment: 1) i agree that its much more clear from domain perspective to have transaction there as anything else actually leaks business rules outside of the app to db, in case of db transactions. i would probably be willing to pay that price but i see the point and i think its a very valid one.

Comment: 2) you have chosen a good name i think, a '`ProductCalculations` placeholder'. The values that it would be initialized with are irrelevant. Lets say its zeros. But i think delete illustrates it even better. Lets consider this...a company does forecasting of their inventory for next period T. And product manager deletes product knowing they wont have it. But accountant steps in and does calculation for it. because delete was not in sync. Furthermore, accountant makes decisions (e.g. cuts some other expenses) since he had to allocate funds for the product for the period T. i hope that explains.

Comment: 2) I am not sure if this is some strange business rule but it sounds so logical for me and very common: different persons/roles manage different aspects of same domain concept and they have to be able to do it concurrently BUT the overall lifetime of the concept (create and delete) must be in sync. Is that really wierd requirement?

Comment: @deezg Do you really think these edge cases could happen if consistency is achieved within a few milliseconds? Yes that's a bit a wierd requirement as I doubt having a floating `ProductCalculations` around for a few milliseconds would really affect the business. Sure, if somehow they end up out of sync for a very long period of time then perhaps the impact could be more important, but how is this likely to happen?

Comment: Well, first of all, let me say that my main goal here is to learn proper ddd way. Second, yes i think they matter. For 2 reasons: 1. i dont want to put my assumptions into solution if i can make solution not depend on assumptions because this kind of assumptions tend to build up rapidly and cause alot of problems rather quickly. 2. Yes, i think its very possible that accountant opens his screen at that fraction of second, dont refresh ui and spends next 2-3 hours thinking he is doing his job but practically losing time.

Comment: And if i can solve it by proper design that its impossible to happen then thats much better for me than thinking about whats the probability of it happening.

Comment: Well, the atomic creation/deletion doesn't solve the above case you mentioned. What if the accountant loads the page and then the product gets deleted? ;) Also, Inventory and Accounting seems like two distinct bounded contexts to me. I'm not saying you shouldn't create/delete both ARs in the same transaction and force your way into EC, but make sure you have the right motivations & reasons for trying to enforce strong consistency here, because there's no real business invariant as far as I can understand.

Comment: this is the reason why i didnt want to discuss all details of the model as its not relevant for the question and would cause huge offtopic:) there are aditional things that prevent the scenario you mention. but my dilemma is around how to handle partially dependant aggregate roots. namely, their creation and deletion.

Comment: It's very hard to ask DDD questions without getting into the details given that DDD is all about the specifics of your domain. If you just want to know how to change two ARs in a single transaction then just use a domain service and call upon two distinct repositories (or do it even directly in the application service method). There's no more complexity than that. You could also use a synchronous event publisher, but that would most likely just makes things more complicated.

Comment: hm...maybe you are right, i am still in a process of digesting it. but i do see a clear rule that accountant is subordinate to product manager and should have green light from product manager to do his accountant work. one of the prerequisites is that product exist. other is task gotten from product manager, for example. now, if product manager shoots out a task but then delete product, its his fault. which additionally can be prevented by additional flags. important difference is that PM is then fully aware of whats going on and that some of his actions are point of no return.

Comment: dont get me wrong, i am actually glad you approach it this way by asking a about business rules. i just dont want to abuse the topic...but definitely very appreciate your effort to understand rules. thank you for that! i am glad to share all thoughts and rules.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you keep thinking about it you will realize that the fact that `ProductCalculationsInitialized` occuring a few milliseconds after `ProductCreated` would be irrelevant. That still doesn't allow accountants to do their work on a product that never existed. If the product gets deleted after the fact and they already have loaded the screen and started to work then strong consistency still doesn't help in this scenario and you still need a mechanism to periodically check the product's state from the UI, which by definition would always be eventually consistent.

Comment: 1. The moment product is created it has to be created also in accountants documents. Regardless of the fact will accountant work on it immediately or not. And accountant is not the one that can create new products. Its a PMs call. 2. You have a state machine which prevents product state going from `Accounting` to `Deleted` as books must be cleared before product can be dissmissed. 3. Now imagine 5-6 different 'things' (bounded contexts?) like accounting where all should be able to work on the product without concurrency issues but still must have create/delete in sync:)

Comment: Well, like I said… the "in sync" is usually an artificial constraint created by developers. From all what you have said so far, I see no reason why eventual consistency wouldn't work. "The moment product is created it has to be created also in accountants documents". This doesn't sound like a business rule. Seems fine enough that accountants know about a newly created product a few milliseconds after it gets created. Think of how the business would work without computers, using paper, it helps. When does the product state switch to `Accounting`?

Comment: Well, without computers we wouldnt be talking ddd nor the same accountant would even be hired by that company as he wouldnt have necessary skills. I think it will get very hard if we try to model non-digital way of doing business into digital frameworks of thoughts. / on the other hand, i think we are focusing a bit too much on 'a few milliseconds' instead of guaranteed atomicity. Can we agree that its more robust and consistent if you have created them transactionally than if you have to think if one succeeded and other failed and have to account for that yourself?

Comment: But i must say your way of thinking is extremely useful! You're definitely raising some questions i haven't thought about.

Comment: There are scenarios where running after strong consistency is actually much harder than eventual consistency in the end. You may also want to read this [Race Conditions Don't Exist](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/) from Udi Dahan.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @plalx in almost every point. However I want to do my bit to the discussion.

I've found that there is usually a very little cost in creating two or more related aggregates inside a single transaction (inside a single bounded context). After all, if those aggregates don't exist yet there cannot be a concurrency conflict, there is no contention and no much difference. Furher, you don't need to deal with partially created state (thinking that state is split between aggregates). It is possible to do that using eventual consistency, and there are situations where that is a better approach, but most of the time there is no great benefit. Even Vernon in his book Implementing Domain-Driven Design mentions this use case as "valid reason to break the rules".

Deleting more than one aggregate is a different story. What should happen if you delete and aggregate that another user is updating at the same time? The probability of such a conflict increases as more aggregates you try to modify/delete in the same transaction. Is there always an upstream/downstream relationship between those aggregates? I mean, if an user deletes `A` and `B` must be also deleted, have the user that is updating `B` no "power" or "voice" to cancel that deletion since she is providing more information to the state of the aggregate?

Those are a very tricky questions and most of the time it is something you need to discuss with a domain expert, and there are very few real scenarios when the answer is something you can't afford with eventual consistency. I discovered that in many cases is preferable to put a "flag" marking the aggregate as "inactive", notifying that will be deleted after some period of time. If no user with enough permission request that aggregate to become active again, then it gets deleted. That helped users to not kill themselves when they delete some aggregate by mistake.

You've mentioned that you don't want a user to spend hours modifying one aggregate if there is a deletion, but that is something that a transaction doesn't contribute much. This is very dependent in the whole architecture, though. That user could have loaded the aggregate into her own memory space and then a deletion occurs. It doesn't matter if you delete inside a transaction, the user is still wasting time. A better solution could be to publish a domain event that triggers some sort of push notification to the user, so she knows that a deletion happened and can stop working (or request a cancellation of that deletion, if you follow such approach).

For the reports and calculations, there are many cases when those "scripts" can skip records where the sibling aggregate is gone, so users doesn't notice there is a missing part or there is no complete consistency yet.

If for some reason you still need to delete several aggregates in the same transaction you just start a transaction in an application service and use repositories to perform the deletion, analogous to the creation case.

So, to summarize:

- The rule of "modify one aggregate per transaction" is not that important when there is a creation of aggregates.
- Deletion of many aggregates works quite well (most of the time) with eventual consistency, and very often just disabling those aggregates, one at a time, is better than performing the deletion immediately.
- Preventing an user from wasting time is better achieved with proper notifications than transactions.
- If there is a real need to perform those actions inside a single transaction, then manage that transaction in the application an be explicit. Using a domain service to perform all the required operations (except for the transaction that is mostly an application concern) brings that logic back to the domain layer.